# Is Boost Thread's boost::unique_lock a scoped lock?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I understand that variable locked by a `boost::mutex::scoped_lock` is automatically unlocked when it is out of scope.

How about `boost::unique_lock`, does it automatically unlock the variable when it is out of scope?

Can anyone also point a reference for that feature as well.

```
double x;
boost::mutex x_mutex;

void foo() 
{
    {
         boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(x_mutex);
         x = rand();
    }    
    ...... some calculation which takes 10 second ......
    ...... is x still locked here??? ......    
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is. The documentation is here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.locks.unique_lock

Comment: If the destructor didn't unlock it, when would it ever get unlocked?

Comment: Its otherway round. `boost::mutex::scoped_lock` is a typedef of `unique_lock`. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types.mutex

Answer (score 12):

**`scoped_lock` is a `unique_lock`.**  In mutex.hpp:

```
typedef unique_lock<mutex> scoped_lock;
```

---

The destructor calls `unlock()` if the lock was acquired. So, it will release when it goes out of scope.

See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html

> not only does it provide for RAII-style locking, it also allows for deferring acquiring the lock until the lock() member function is called explicitly, or trying to acquire the lock in a non-blocking fashion, or with a timeout. Consequently, unlock() is only called in the destructor if the lock object has locked the Lockable object, or otherwise adopted a lock on the Lockable object.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. If a boost::unique_lock is automatically unlocked when it goes out of scope, then what's the difference between boost::unique_lock and boost::mutex::scoped_lock? Thanks.

Comment: Also thank you for pointing out the reference, but I am a little bit confused here, does it mean destructor is automatically called when it is out of scope?

Comment: `scoped_lock` is a typedef for `unique_lock<mutex>`. automatic vars declared in a block {} are destructed when the end of the block is reached making the [RAII pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) possible.

Comment: Also, in C++11, they have gotten rid of typedef so there is only unique_lock now.